# 2D array of function pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c, 2d, typedef

I am trying to understand the approach recommended at https://aticleworld.com/state-machine-using-c/ for implementing a state machine. I don't understand two things:

1. Can a 2D table be initialized like this? (when I compile the same with GCC version 9.3.0, I am getting compilation errors.)

```
// Table to define valid states and event of finite state machine
    static afEventHandler StateMachine =
    {
        [Idle_State] ={[Card_Insert_Event]= InsertCardHandler },
        [Card_Inserted_State] ={[Pin_Enter_Event] = EnterPinHandler },
        [Pin_Eentered_State] ={[Option_Selection_Event] = OptionSelectionHandler},
        [Option_Selected_State] ={[Amount_Enter_Event] = EnterAmountHandler},
        [Amount_Entered_State] ={[Amount_Dispatch_Event] = AmountDispatchHandler},
    };
```

2. what is the meaning of the following typedef?

```
typedef eSystemState (*const afEventHandler[last_State][last_Event])(void);
```

Please explain. Thank you!!

Comment: Why wouldn’t you show the error messages when posting this question? Do you not realize that the error messages contain information about what the errors are?

Comment: Copying the code from the linked article and compiling it reveals two issues, one that `ReadEvent` is not declared and one that a useless instance of `eNewEvent` is defined outside a loop that contains its own definition. The code shown in this question compiles without error in that context. So any errors are likely due to copying it incorrectly or incompletely or using incompatible compiler options (perhaps requesting something other than ordinary C). Show the error messages and edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: The question to question 2 is in the title.